# Can't install Clownfish from cpan under Cygwin

Tags: perl, makefile, cygwin, cpan

I do not understand what goes wrong here:

```
cpan[1]> install Clownfish
Going to read '/home/y/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Wed, 26 Nov 2014
Running install for module 'Clownfish'
Running make for C/CR/CREAMYG/Clownfish-0.4.1.tar.gz
Checksum for /home/y/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/CR/CREAMYG/Clownfish-0.4.1.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /home/y/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................DONE
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----      CREAMYG/Clownfish-0.4.1.tar.gz      ----
    Clownfish::CFC::Perl::Build [build_requires]
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
  Delayed until after prerequisites
```

The error message says "Make had some problems". I have this `make` in Cygwin:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.0
Built for i686-pc-cygwin
Copyright (C) 1988-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in Perl prior to version 5.18. (Works fine with latest Strawberry Perl, which at the moment is version 5.20.)